# How to get the list of annotations of a class and its superclass

Tags: java, inheritance, reflection, annotations

I'm writing a method supposed to retrieve all annotations of a specific method declaring class and its superclasses.

By using the method `getAnnotations()` on the declaring class, the resulting table contains only the declaring class annotations and the superclass annotations are ignored.
If I remove the annotations of the declaring class, then the superclass annotation are present.

What am I missing here?

The simplified method retrieving the annotations :

```
public void check(Method invokedMethod) {
    for (Annotation annotation : invokedMethod.getDeclaringClass().getAnnotations()) {
        // Do something ...
    }
}
```

(All annotations I'm trying the get have the `@Inherited` annotation)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case you need to process several annotations of the same type, the standard approach is does not work, because annotations are stored in a `Map` with annotation types as the key. (See more [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/lang/Class.java#3417)). Here is how I would work around this problem (just go through all super classes manually):

```
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Inherited;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class AnnotationReflectionTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        check(Class2.class.getMethod("num", new Class[0]));
    }

    public static void check(Method invokedMethod) {
        Class<?> type = invokedMethod.getDeclaringClass();
        while (type != null) {
            for (Annotation annotation : type.getDeclaredAnnotations()) {
                System.out.println(annotation.toString());
            }
            type = type.getSuperclass();
        }
    }
}

@Inherited
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface Annot1 {
    int num();
}

@Annot1(num = 5)
class Class1 {
    public int num() {
        return 1;
    }
}

@Inherited
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface Annot2 {
    String text();
}

@Annot2(text = "ttt")
class Class2 extends Class1 {
    public int num() {
        return super.num() + 1;
    }
}
```

What version of Java and what OS do you use?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, I'm using java 8 on mac os X. Your code is pretty similar to mine I don't really anderstand the behaviour... I'll look at it again as soon as I go home.

Comment: Seems to be a good workaround for my problem. Thanks for your time !

Answer (score 3):

I had to write a simple method with

```
private <A extends Annotation> A getAnnotationFromType(Class<?> classType, final Class<A> annotationClass) {
    
    while ( !classType.getName().equals(Object.class.getName()) ) {
        
        if ( classType.isAnnotationPresent(annotationClass)) {
            return classType.getAnnotation(annotationClass);
        }
        classType = classType.getSuperclass();
    }
    return null;
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be obvious to most people, but if you came here looking for [fields of a class and its superclasses](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/class/classMembers.html), you can use

```
myClass.getFields()
```

to get all fields, also of superclasses, instead of

```
myClass.getDeclaredFields()
```

which only returns the fields of the class itself. Similarly for methods and constructors.