# Is there any way to obtain all super annotations on a class?

Tags: java, reflection

For example:

```
@SubAnnotation
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Annotation[] annotations = Test.class.getAnnotations();
        for(Annotation annot: annotations){
            System.out.println(annot);
        }
    }
}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@SuperAnnotation
public @interface SubAnnotation {
}
```

How to obtain SuperAnnotation on Test.class?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the list of annotations of a class and its superclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32467494/how-to-get-the-list-of-annotations-of-a-class-and-its-superclass)

Comment: The concept you're looking for is called _meta-annotation_.

Comment: @pczeus Annotations-from-superclass are not the subject of this question.